# row of 5 responsive images at bottom of section? must stay on 1 line, img cannot get 'cropped'

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, responsive

Beginner coder in over their head!

I am trying to set 5 images over a background image for a main page:
Issues with
1. setting row of images at the bottom of the screen in a responsive template and 
2. having them fit the full screen while
3. staying in the same row

[here's an image of what I'd like for it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J2ng.png)

I am using a template and the code is all over the place.  Hoping you guys had some ideas of where to start with this

Comment: use bootstrap grid system for that

Comment: Show the code you're working with. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: here's a start https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jweRGQ

Answer (score 0):

Grid system demo using Bootstrap 4. If you want to use full width, remove `<div class="container">` and its closing tag.

```css
.row img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.row .col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/History-of-Icons-Flat-Design-Website.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      4 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      5 of 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```